# how to execute in query with mysql pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i want to execute a query with `mysql` `pdo`

the `query` is

```
SELECT * FROM `user_skills` WHERE skills in ('html','css')
```

**see the executed screen below**

[image]

i'm getting data in this format

```
    $skills = array('html','css');

            $sql = "SELECT first_name,last_name,mobile_number,prev_comany_name,user_id FROM user_details WHERE  skills=:input";                               
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue("input", $skills);            
            $stmt->execute();

   /** foreach($skills as $skill){
       echo $skill;
    } **/
```

Comment: What error you have got...?

Comment: You can't input an array directly into prepare like that. Just take your original query, replace the user inputs with your flags then bind them.

Comment: do you want skills to match both 'html' and 'css'?

Comment: @SamerAbuGahgah,    yes the `html` , `css` is coming from an `array`, so i tried like that

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an array o the `bindValue()` function, and you can't test to equality with multiple values in the query instead you need to use the `in`  operator. Then you can implode the array to pass a string to the `bindValue()` function:

```
$skills = array('html','css');

            $sql = "SELECT first_name,last_name,mobile_number,prev_comany_name,user_id FROM user_details WHERE  skills IN (:input)";                               
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(":input", implode(",", $skills), PDO::PARAM_STR);            
            $stmt->execute();

   /** foreach($skills as $skill){
       echo $skill;
    }
```

Comment: Change `implode(","$skills)` to `implode("," ,$skills)`

Comment: @SamerAbuGahgah, now i'm getting this `error`   `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in `

Comment: I've edited the answer can you try it now, and tell me if you got same error @EaB

Comment: @SamerAbuGahgah, `query` is `executing` but  i'm getting `blank result` why?  despite `html` and `css` are present

Comment: @EaB the image you posted shows another table or what,

Comment: @EaB change $sql to $sql =" SELECT * FROM `user_skills` WHERE skills in (:input)"; and try it out again

Comment: @SamerAbuGahgah, those `skills` are present in the `posted` table

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution referring this `thread`  [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

note `FIND_IN_SET`

```
$skills = array('html','css');
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, :array)
$skills = implode(',', $skills); 
$stmt->bindParam('array', $skills);
```

Answer (score -1):

change code to :

```
  $skills = array('html','css');

  $sql = "SELECT first_name,last_name,mobile_number,prev_comany_name,user_id FROM user_details WHERE  skills IN (:input)";                               
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindValue(":input", "'".implode("','", $skills)."'");            
  $stmt->execute();
```